# Variable name out of an array value

Tags: sas

I have a data similar to this
(This won't work because of an  Array subscript out of range error):

```
    data test;
    array id {5} (1, 8, 4, 12, 23);
    array a_ {5};
    do i = 1 to 5;
        a_[id[i]] = id[i];
    end;
    run;
```

what I want to do is,
create variables begins with 'a_' and the values of array id.
Meaning : a_1, a_8, a_4, a_12, a_23

This will only work if I declare array a_ with 23 members:

```
    data test;
    array id {5} (1, 8, 4, 12, 23);
    array a_ {23};
    do i = 1 to 5;
        a_[id[i]] = id[i];
    end;
    run;
```

But then I get lots of missing variables I don't need.
I only want the above 5.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PROC TRANSPOSE is usually the easiest way to do this.

First, make a vertical dataset like so:

```
data vert;
  array id[5] (1,8,4,12,23);
  do _i = 1 to dim(id);
    varname = cats('A_',id[_i]);
    vvalue = 1; *it is not apparent to me what the value should be in A_12 or whatnot;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Then PROC TRANSPOSE makes your desired dataset.

```
proc transpose data=vert out=want;
  id varname;
  var vvalue;
run;
```